# AJAX removes JSF form event handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2, event-handling

I have a JSF page with a form, with the following 2 somewhat nonstandard requirements:

1. Some input components are only relevant for certain settings of other inputs. I.e., if a certain value is chosen in a `<h:selectOneMenu>`, another field should be shown or hidden as appropriate.

   This is handled via a `<f:ajax render="@form">` and the `rendered` attribute. Simple.
2. I need to call some Javscript code on **submit** and **reset** before the request is posted to the server.

   This is handled by adding event handlers to the form element for the `onsubmit` and `onreset` events, via jQuery, in the `$(document).ready()` event handler. Not difficult either.

What I however find is that once the AJAX POST request happens, the `onsubmit` and `onreset` event handlers disappear. Obviously the `$(document).ready()` handler is not activated again, so they are not recreated - but it is strange that they are removed.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or a better (correct) way to accomplish this?

### Basic Facelets page for demonstration purposes:

(no backing bean needed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
<h:head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <h:outputScript target="head" library="js" name="jquery.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript target="body">
        //Code just for debugging purposes
        function debugAjax(data) {
            console.log("AJAX onevent. Type=" + data.type + ", Status=" + data.status);
            debugEvents();
        }
        function debugEvents() {
            var evs = jQuery._data(document.getElementById('myform'), 'events');
            if (evs) {
                jQuery.each(evs, function(index, value) {
                    console.log(" - Event " + index + "=" + value);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(" - NO EVENTS");
            }
        }
    </h:outputScript>

    <h:outputScript target="body">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("Adding handlers");
            jQuery("#myform").on({
                reset  : function() { console.log("RESET activated"); },
                submit : function() { console.log("SUBMIT activated"); }
            });
            debugEvents();
        })
    </h:outputScript>

    <h:form id="myform">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="formType" value="Form type" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="formType" value="#{formType}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Simple" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="With additional data" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Another item" />

                <f:ajax render="@form" onevent="debugAjax" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <ui:remove>conditionally displayed field</ui:remove>
            <h:outputLabel for="moreData" value="More data" rendered="#{formType eq '2'}" />
            <h:inputText id="moreData" value="#{moreData}"  rendered="#{formType eq '2'}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton type="reset" id="delete" value="Cancel" />
        <h:commandButton type="submit" id="submit" value="OK" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

### Console output:

This is the output in my Javascript console (explanations inside {{}} added)

```
{{Initial load of page}}
GET http://localhost:8080/xxx/test.jsf [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6ms]
"Adding handlers"
" - Event reset=[object Object]"
" - Event submit=[object Object]"
{{reset/submit event handlers work as expected}}
{{now changing dropdown that fires AJAX}}
POST http://localhost:8080/xxx/test.jsf [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 9ms]
"AJAX onevent. Type=event, Status=begin"
" - Event reset=[object Object]"
" - Event submit=[object Object]"
"AJAX onevent. Type=event, Status=complete"
" - Event reset=[object Object]"
" - Event submit=[object Object]"
"AJAX onevent. Type=event, Status=success"
" - NO EVENTS"
{{reset/submit event handlers DON'T work, but standard form resetting/submitting still works}}
```

The test was run from Firefox, GlassFish 4.1 (13) (Mojarra 2.2.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the AJAX call should render only some or all contents **inside** the form. In the above sample, it would do nicely to give an `id` to the `<h:panelGrid>`:

```
<h:panelGrid id="fieldgrid" columns="2">
```

... and then render that in the AJAX call:

```
<f:ajax render="fieldgrid" ... />
```